# call same named method of two different class in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am facing a challenge in LWC. I have two classes let's say `class1` and `class2` both these classes have same named method as `fun1`. i want to call `fun1` method in my lightning web component wire method. how can i do this?

**class1:**

```
public with sharing class Class1 {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<Account> fun1(){
        return [select id , name from Account limit 10];
    }
}
```

**class2:**

```
public with sharing class Class2 {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<Account> fun1(){
        return [select id , name from Account limit 20];
    }
}
```

**LWC Component js file :**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import  fun1 from '@salesforce/apex/Class1 .fun1';
import  fun1 from '@salesforce/apex/Class2 .fun1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is give the functions different aliases in the LWC JavaScript. For example:

```
import class1fun1 from '@salesforce/apex/Class1.fun1';
import class2fun1 from '@salesforce/apex/Class2.fun1';
```

You then use them as class1fun1() and class2fun1() in the code.

Comment: As Addition: This is working in this case because that are default exports. When you have named exports (syntax with curly braces) you have to use aliasing like "fun1 as somethingelse" where you are then using "somethingelse" as identifier

Comment: @Renji-xD apex exports only support default export format, though, so there's no problem there.

Comment: ya - but knowing why sth works makes always sense. When he next time wants to do the same for e. g. imports from own utility modules he don`t need to create a question why its then not working as expected ;)

Comment: IMHO that would be an entirely different question and worth having its own question and answer separately so people will find it with a search. For me, question was purely about Apex AuraEnabled method imports. Not to say what you mention isn't interesting to be aware of... :)